# First line of erlang sasl log binary encoded?

Tags: erlang

We have noticed something strange with our latest release. Typically, our sasl log has a long list of processes starting, etc at the top of the log. With a release we just put-out we have begun noticing that the first line is binary for some reason. We have not modified the start-up or the sasl config that we know of. Are there any reasons that this may be the case?

**Adding result of HEAD command for first line**

0000000 nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul
*
207070600 nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul nul  nl
207070613

**Additional thought**

One thing that did change recently was that we added the compress option to our logrotate.conf. Is there any chance this could be related?

Comment: What is the content of the first line?

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine that.

Comment: Try `head -1 sasl.log | od -a`.

Comment: I added the results to the OP.